# Cloudflare integration with Azure websites

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, cname-record, cloudflare

On cloudflare, I have given below details for example.com

```
A record pointing to Azure IP
www CNAME record to example.azurewebsites.net
```

Cloudflare routing is working for example.com and www.example.com
However, any request to example.azurewebsites.net are directly routed to azure network. How can I route requests to example.azurewebsites.net through cloudflare.

Essentially cloudflare DDOS protection is nullified if attacker hits the origin example.azurewebsites.net

I am also aware Azure has a DDOS prevention capability

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DNS settings for your website in Cloudflare allow you to proxy traffic so that requests to `example.com` and `www.example.com` will be protected.

You do not control `azurewebsites.net` though so you cannot proxy traffic going directly to that address with Cloudflare, which means that someone can get around the Cloudflare protection by just going to `example.azurewebsites.net`

What you can do to protect against this is use the IP and Domain Restrictions feature of Azure Websites to restrict traffic so your website will only respond to requests coming through Cloudflare.

Instructions for configuring your site are here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/

You can get the list of Cloudflare IPs here: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This is the only real way to protect the original hostname on Azure websites... @faiz let me know if I understood your question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare will work with CNAME records, just add a CNAME to your DNS records and make sure they are orange clouded.

If you see an [orange cloud](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169626-What-subdomains-are-appropriate-for-orange-gray-clouds-) icon next to the relevant DNS record your traffic will pass through CloudFlare.

[image: Orange Clouded]

Comment: You cannot control or proxy azurewebsites.net, that's a public domain owned by Microsoft...

Comment: The idea is you CNAME to it from another domain; you have control of that domain as the author clearly demonstrated.

Comment: Read the question again, the OP is asking about the origin address that is still available to the public